# Converting static framework to dynamic

Tags: xcode, clang, ld, comscore

I want to convert static iOS framework (https://github.com/comScore/ComScore-iOS-watchOS-tvOS/tree/master/ComScore/iOS) into dynamic.

`> clang -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk -lc++ -F . -framework ComScore -ObjC -o ComScoreDynamic`

This command is successful, however, there is a problem with symbol visibility.

When I check symbols in the original framework it is around 4k of public symbols:

`> nm -gU ComScore.framework/ComScore | wc -l
4387`

In dynamic version only very few of them:

`nm -gU ComScoreDynamic

0000000000114af8 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORCommonUtils
0000000000114940 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORCrossPublisherIdSourceValue
0000000000114a08 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORHTTP
0000000000114990 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORHelper
0000000000114aa8 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORObfuscation
0000000000114a80 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORReachability
0000000000114918 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORUniqueId
0000000000114b20 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCORCommonUtils
00000000001149e0 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCORCrossPublisherIdSourceValue
0000000000114a30 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCORHTTP
0000000000114968 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCORHelper
0000000000114ad0 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCORObfuscation
0000000000114a58 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCORReachability
00000000001149b8 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SCORUniqueId
00000000001166b0 D __ZTINSt3__117bad_function_callE
00000000000d5d60 S __ZTSNSt3__117bad_function_callE`

All other symbols marked as internal (`t` and `s` markings).

How can I keep symbols external?

UPDATE:

Looks like this can be similar problem: [Export an `OBJC_CLASS` from one static lib as part of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275070/export-an-objc-class-from-one-static-lib-as-part-of-another)

Problem is that symbols in static lib are exported as `private_extern` and there is no way to preserve them in dynamic library.

Comment: You don't need making everything in the lib external. Make proper dynamic .framework, with module exports, like http://nsomar.com/modular-framework-creating-and-using-them/

Comment: Thanks for the response! As far as I know, module.map affects only compilation time, and I have an Issue at link phase. If I will create custom module map, it will affect resulting lib?

Also, I cannot see any references to module map in Xcode link command for regular dynamic frameworks.

Comment: As you've seen, symbols are not stripped, so ObjC runtime will find them. Why do you consider it an issue? How do you use dynamic lib?

Comment: I receive an error during linking this dynamic library to my app:

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORReducedRequirementsStreamingAnalytics`

In original library, this symbol is marked as external:

`---------------- D _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORReducedRequirementsStreamingAnalytics`

And is internal in dynamic:

`000000000011aac0 s _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORReducedRequirementsStreamingAnalytics`

Comment: So the class names are still required be external. That's interesting.

Comment: Use `nm -m` : in your static library symbols are "private external", they should be "external".

Comment: Thanks for the useful information! Can I move symbols to another section in a static lib?

Answer (score 2):

The public symbols in the comScore framework are marked `private external`. This can be seen with the `nm` utility and looking for the SCORAnalytics class:

```
nm -m ComScore/iOS/ComScore.framework/Versions/A/ComScore  |grep _OBJC_CLASS_\$_SCORAnalytics
```

Shows:

```
---------------- (LTO,DATA) private external _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCORAnalytics
```

This means the symbol can only be linked against once. When Cocoapods performs a pre-link for secondary ('transitive') dependencies, these symbols lose their `extern` attribute. The idea here is to prevent public symbols from a dependency from leaking into those of another library. The problem is that, for Swift projects, they aren't fully resolved until the final app link; by that point they're no longer available.

The real issue is that the comScore library is a *static* framework. The best solution would be for comScore to release it as a dynamic framework, but these are only supported by iOS 8 and above; comScore insists on support all the way back to iOS 6. I know.

For now, my solution is to include the comScore framework directly in our Cocoapod and vend it within the Podspec, allowing it to work with both Obj-C and Swift projects. The downside is I have to manually update our Cocoapod every time comScore releases a new version. There would also be symbol conflicts if another pod included comScore, but since our pod is a metrics aggregator that logs to several backends, it's likely to be the only metrics component in use. YMMV.